# .Net Core XUnit - No test source files were specified using "dotnet test"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, testing, xunit

I understand this might sound a minor issue. I have .net core project with xUnit.

I can run xUnitin visual studio in my development environment.

I can also run tests in console `dotnet test Test.dll`. (after publish)

But I have another machine(build machine), where I take my published code and try to run "dotnet test", and it throws

```
No test source files were specified.
```

This is my test.csproj file, I have installed every recommended packages(I think so).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.9.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="5.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Respawn" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.4.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.msbuild" Version="2.4.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Apart from this, I have `.Net Core 3.1 sdk` installed on my build machine.

With all this done, shouldn't `dotnet test` identify testcases?

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: xunit.runner.visualstudio is the package that allows `dotnet test` to understand the xUnit tests. The dll, xunit.runner.visualstudio.dll, should be found in the same place as your test dll - could you check for this on the build server? You've said that you take "published code" to the build server. If you mean that you've published your application then your test dlls and related xUnit dlls will probably not be included. Ideally you will have the entire application source code brought onto the build server and have `dotnet test` build and run the tests itself.

Comment: @Andy thanks for you comments, however published code works in another development environment which I have. It only fails on my build servers. So I am guessing this has something to do with environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for solution for hours, finally I found this.

Issue was with running parallel tests on my build machine.

Apparently build machine was not able to run tests in parallel.

This is how I resolved it.

1. Added a `xunit.runner.json` file in my test project
2. Added below json to the file.

   `{ "parallelizeAssembly": false, "parallelizeTestCollections": false }`

On next Pipeline, it ran without issue.